# Transparent gif showing white background when placing it on another image

Tags: css, gif

I am trying to show a transparent loading gif while another image loads. Here I am placing the loading gif in the center of actual image.

But the problem is the transparent loading gif showing white background when I am showing it over another image. (Please see below picture)

[image]

I have tested it by creating a small html snippet to show the gif over a div, but here it is showing transparent background. (please see the below picture)

[image]

What is the problem here? Any ideas?

Comment: can you show us the relevant css and HTML for the white background showing? The issue will be there likely. Can you post a sample on jsfiddle? Could it be inheriting the white background from somewhere else?

Comment: Please provide some of your code in a fiddle or other useful tool